# Does convergence of $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}n a_n$ imply the absolute convergence of $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Does the convergence of
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}n a_n
$$
imply convergence of:

$$
A = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n
$$

$$
B = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left| a_n\right|
$$

$$
C = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sqrt{n} a_n
$$

Using the limit criteria it looks like A and C are indeed convergent too. Could you point me in the right direction with sum B?

Comment: On A and C, be careful: the limit comparison test only applies to series of nonnegative terms, so it won't apply here.

Comment: Hint for what does work on A and C: Dirichlet's test.

Comment: @DanielSchepler how should one apply Dirichlet's test here?

Comment: In example C, I have used Dirichlet like this: $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} n a_n$. Since $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$  is monotonically decreasing and its limit is 0, and $n a_n$ converges, hence is bounded, the entire series is convergent. After simplifying we end up with expected $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sqrt{n} a_n$. Is that correct assumption?

Comment: Precisely, $\sum_{n=0}^\infty n a_n$ convergent means exactly the sequence of partial sums $(\sum_{k=0}^n k a_k)_{n=0}^\infty$ is convergent, which implies that the sequence of partial sums is bounded.  (Well, technically you need to be careful of the fact that $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ is undefined at $n=0$ but that's not hard to work around.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try looking at the case $a_n = \frac{(-1)^n}{n \log n}$.

Comment: Great! That's the counter example I was looking for.